# Problem with Bevel

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bevel

I am new to Blender.

I have currently modeled a shape on which I would like to apply a "Bevel". However, when I apply it, I don't see any changes.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

My current model:
[image: current]

I want this :
[image: I want this]

My settings:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely in the geometry. Bevel modifier has Clamp Overlap enabled by default. This means it will stop the bevel if there is some geometry in the mesh that is too close to some other geometry and would produce overlapping messy results.

You could disable Clamp Overlap, but then you will get those messy overlaps somewhere on your model:

[image]

As you can see I have edges in the GIF that are closer to each other than the distance needed for the bevel, so bevel stops at the point where it would overlap with Clamp Overlap enabled and produces messy overlapping geometry if Clamp Overlap is disabled.

You could try selecting all in edit mode(<kbd>A</kbd>) and hitting <kbd>M</kbd> followed by <kbd>B</kbd> to merge vertices by distance so you fix overlapping vertices. That might fix the issue in some cases. In other cases, you might need to fix the geometry manually.

Sometimes it helps to have more control over what edges get beveled. You could limit bevel by vertex group or edge bevel weight:

[image]

And then adjust Bevel Weight for selected edges:

[image]

Or make some vertex group:

[image]

This way you could only bevel edges that do not have this problem which in some cases might be the desired result.

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your explanation! It helped me a lot!